# What are the most common ways of closing an open world?

Tags: maps, world-design

In many open world games, there are several ways to limit them. From original ones such as Desynchronisation(Assasins' Creed) to invisible walls.

What are the most common ways to close open worlds?

Comment: This is subjective / vague ... do you need help with solving a problem? What have you tried / not tried? ... yes those are existing ways to close open worlds, another might be to use zones.

Comment: If there is a limit, then it isn't an open world.

Comment: By open world I mean that there isn't a linear map, like portal, but an open one, like Skyrim.

Comment: [Here's a related narrower question on how to do this without feeling artificial](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112272/how-can-i-create-borders-in-an-open-world-game-that-dont-feel-artificial?s=11|1.7027)

Answer (score 3):

#### Infinite Water or Land

Of all the techniques I have encountered I find this the most appealing. It doesn't kill you, it gives sense of continuity and doesn't pull you away from the open world sense. Examples Far Cry 3. GTA V.

Others include:

- Killing the player using killer robots, monsters etc.
- Artificial Boundaries. You hit a boundary, used in older games.
- Natural Boundaries Mountains or valleys.
- Journey also used Wind, which throws the player down the mountain.

Comment: There is also the "You are leaving the play area!  Return now or you will be (killed|respawned)"